# how for any $(a , e)$ we will get an ellipse on the double cone by the intersection of a Plane and the cone

Tags: conic-sections

I understand Dandelin spheres.

But I can not understand how for any $(a , e)$ we will get an ellipse on the double cone by the intersection of a Plane and the cone.

Here $a$ is the half of the major axis and $e$ is the eccentricity.

Comment: Do you mean a "cone of revolution" ? Because the word "cone" can also designate a "broader"  family... In such a case, it would be sufficient to place your ellipse anywhere on the horizontal plane, take an arbitrary point $S$ with a $z \ne 0$ and connect $S$ to all points of the ellipse...

Comment: You can reduce your investigation to a planar section of the (looked for) cone along the semimajor axis of the ellipse. As you know the Dandelin spheres, you could find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3251776) interesting.

Comment: See if this can be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651714/from-ellipse-equation-to-circular-cone-axis/2651961#2651961

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/137462/409) (which you've read), eccentricity is the ratio $e=\sin U/\sin V$ (where $U$ is the angle of inclination of the cutting plane, and $V$ is the angle made by (the generators of) the surface of the cone). Varying $U$ from $0$ to $V$ gives every eccentricity from $0$ (circle) to $1$ (parabola), so every elliptic *shape* occurs somewhere. To account for every *size*, we vary how far the cutting plane's intersection with the axis is from the vertex; everything "scales" to get every $a$ from $0$ to $\infty$. (continued)

Comment: (continuing) To get hyperbolas, one uses a cutting plane that's steeper than the cone (so that the plane cuts both nappes of the cone); that is, $U>V$ and likewise $\sin U> \sin V$, making $e=\sin U/\sin V> 1$. Interestingly, since $\sin U\leq 1$, the largest eccentricity achievable with an angle-$V$ cone is $1/\sin V$. So, although every ellipse, and the parabola, appears as a section of a given cone, not every hyperbola does. To get all hyperbolas, you need to vary the cone's angle as well.

Comment: I know how to get ellipses with all eccentricity.  If I keep fixed the point of intersection of the plane and the axis of the conic and move the plane in such a manner that the inclination angle runs from $V$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ , we will get ellipses with all possible eccentricity. But my question is how can I get an ellipse with the major axis of length $d$.  Is there any method we can do so ?@Blue

Comment: I think the eccentricity will be $\frac{\cos U}{\cos V}$ not $\frac{\sin U}{\sin V}$ as V is fixed and we are varying the angle U. When U>V , we should get ellipse ; that is $e<1$.@Blue

Answer (score 2):

Expanding-upon a comment ...

---

As mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/137462/409) the eccentricity of a conic is given by
$$e = \frac{\sin U}{\sin V} \tag1$$
where $U$ is the angle of inclination of the cutting plane, and $V$ is the angle of (the generators of) the cone.*

By varying $U$ from $O$ to $V$, the value of $e$ varies from $0$ (circle) to $1$ (parabola), so that every ellipse *shape* is achieved by simply tilting the plane.

To achieve every possible *size*, we vary the distance from the cutting plane to the cone's vertex. For specificity, consider this "side view" of the situation, with the cutting plane meeting the cone's axis at $P$, and the vertices of the resulting ellipse are $Q$ and $R$.

[image]

The Law of Sines tells us that, in $\triangle PVQ$,
$$\frac{q}{\sin\angle PVQ}=\frac{p}{\sin\angle PQV} \quad\to\quad
\frac{q}{\sin(90^\circ-V)}=\frac{p}{\sin(V+U)} \quad\to\quad
q = \frac{p\cos V}{\sin(V+U)} \tag2$$
and likewise, in $\triangle PVR$,
$$\frac{r}{\sin\angle PVR}=\frac{p}{\sin\angle PRV} \quad\to\quad
\frac{r}{\sin(90^\circ-V)}=\frac{p}{\sin(V-U)} \quad\to\quad
r = \frac{p\cos V}{\sin(V-U)} \tag3$$

Consequently, $|QR|$, the major axis of the ellipse, is given by
$$|QR| = q+r = \frac{p\cos V(\sin(V-U)+\sin(V+U))}{\sin(V-U)\sin(V+U)}
= \frac{p\cos U\sin 2V}{\sin(V-U)\sin(V+U)} \tag4$$

(Sanity check: When $U=0$, this reduces to $2p\cot V$, the width of the cone at the level of $P$, as we would expect with a circle. When $U=V$, $\sin(V-U)=0$ so that the length becomes infinite, as we would expect with a parabola.)

So, for a given pair of angles $U$ and $V$, we can choose $p$ so that $(4)$ yields whatever major axis length we desire.

---

*These angles are measured against "the horizontal". If instead one chooses to measure against, say, the "vertical" axis of the cone, then the ratio would be $\cos U/\cos V$.

I prefer sines, as they make zero-values correspond to zero-angles, so that in particular a circle ($e=0$) corresponds to a horizontal cutting plane with $0^\circ$ inclination.